# Opportunity Field Dependency

Tags: salesforce

in my code below the field dependency doesn't work.
I read here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_dependent_picklists.htm that should work. The dependency should work automatically if I add the fields to my page, but it doesn't.

```
<apex:pageblock title="Verkaufschancen Übersicht" id="pbOpp" mode="inlineEdit" rendered="{!AccDList2.size>0}">
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
    <apex:commandButton action="{!SaveNewOpp}" value="Save" id="saveButton1" rerender="pbOpp, pbAccPlan" rendered="{!IF(newOpp=1,true,false)}"/>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!CancelNewOpp}" value="Cancel" id="cancelButton1" immediate="true" rendered="{!IF(newOpp=1,true,false)}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!IF(newOpp=1,true,false)}" columns="2">
    <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.RecordTypeId}" required="true"/>    
    <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.Name}" required="true"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.StageName}" required="true"/>        
    <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.Amount}" required="true"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.Probability}" required="true"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.Bewertung_in__c}" required="true"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.CloseDate}" required="true"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

```
Public PageReference SaveNewOpp() {
Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
opp.AccountId = SelectedAccountId;
opp.Name = oppString.Name;
opp.StageName = oppString.StageName;
opp.Amount = oppString.Amount;
opp.Probability = oppString.Probability;
opp.CloseDate = oppString.CloseDate;
opp.RecordTypeId = oppString.RecordTypeId;
opp.Bewertung_in__c = oppString.Bewertung_in__c;
INSERT opp;
RETURN NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which are the dependent fields in your example.

What is exact problem, is the dependent field not changed when you change controlling field or they are not saved properly?